# How can random.shuffle result in a KeyError?

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, shuffle, keyerror

I just got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./download_documents.py", line 153, in <module>
    paragraphs, used_pages = find_pages(lang, to_extract)
  File "./download_documents.py", line 67, in find_pages
    random.shuffle(page_titles_queue)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 291, in shuffle
    x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
KeyError: 1
```

Which confuses me quite a bit.

1. `random.shuffle` seems to work on zero-element lists and on one-element lists.
2. `page_titles_queue` is a list of tuples.
3. Two lines *after* the `random.shuffle(page_titles_queue)`, there is `page_titles_queue.pop()`, but that should not affect the shuffle. Right?

So what are possible reasons for the KeyError?

I use `Python 2.7.12` on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I now let the same code run again. Let's see what happens.

Comment: Chances are you're mistaken about what `page_titles_queue` actually is.

Comment: You're running it on a dict: `random.shuffle(dict.fromkeys([1, 2, 3]))`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary ooops ... you are right. Should I delete the question? I guess that this could be useful for others. Do you want to post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`random.shuffle` just exchanges items, the line where the exception happened makes this perfectly clear:

```
x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

Where `x` is the "sequence" that was passed in. In this case `i` and `j` will be values in the range `range(0, len(x))` and if any of these `i` or `j` isn't present in the "sequence" it will throw an `Exception`. In your case it's very likely given that it throws a `KeyError`:

```
>>> import random
>>> d = {i: i for i in range(7, 10)}
>>> random.shuffle(d)
KeyError: 3
```

However it works by exchanging the values in case the dictionary contains exactly the keys that make up the `range(0, len(x))`:

```
>>> d = {i: i for i in range(10)}
>>> random.shuffle(d)
>>> d
{0: 7, 1: 9, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 0, 5: 2, 6: 1, 7: 6, 8: 8, 9: 5}
```

If one or multiple keys are missing it could work or it could throw an `Exception`. That depends on which random numbers will be drawn:

```
d = {i: i for i in range(1, 10)}
random.shuffle(d)   # works sometimes, but sometimes it throws the KeyError
```

Comment: Hi, Can you provide some other ways we can shuffle the lists?
Like I got to know of `random.sample(your_list, len(your_list)` It doesn't disturb the order of original list and returns the shuffled list